# Jenkins: How to resolve resolve plugin errors?

Tags: jenkins

I have a server on which Jenkins(2.12) is installed.

There are no plugins are installed(actually I uninstalled every plugin from the plugin manager), though I get the error messages complaining about something related to the plugin dependency.

How can I get rid of this error?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Removing the corresponding plugins did the trick.

Plugin location ↓

`$JENKINS_HOME/plugins/name_of_plugins`